# Toggle .dragscrollable() on selected element

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin https://github.com/mvlandys/jquery.dragscrollable to make an element movable by drag scroll, but I only want to be able to do this while the "move" tool is selected.

I can't see how to disable the dragscrollable plugin once it has been enabled?

..or how would I use it so that it only drag-scrolls while the move tool is selected?

```
$('.dd-tool').click(function(){
    if ($('#dd-tool-move').hasClass('selected')){
        $('#edit-window').dragscrollable();
    }else{
        //stop the dragscroll plugin???
    };
})
```

Comment: That plugin has no api to switch off.  You can use ugly hacks to stop  plugin. But possible it's better to search another one?

Comment: Fair enough. I am now using https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic and have it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Vasiliy, that plugin has no API to switch it off. Instead I am using this plugin https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic

```
$('.dd-tool').click(function(){
    if ($('#dd-tool-move').hasClass('selected')){
        $('#edit-window').kinetic('attach');
    }else{
        $('#edit-window').kinetic('detach');
    }
});
```